# numeric vs alphanumeric sort on ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: bash, sorting, ubuntu, numeric

I am getting some strange behavior on sort utility on Ubuntu 18.04.2. Here's some sequence  of commands issued. How can I ensure numeric sort for all the columns? column 1, 2, 3, 4 should be in order.

```
$ cat zz
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0
1   1   0   0
1   1   1   0
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
10  10  10  10
1   1   10  1
1   1   100 1

$ cat zz | sort 
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0
10  10  10  10
1   1   0   0
1   1   1   0
1   1   100 1
1   1   10  1
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2

$ cat zz | sort -n
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0
1   1   0   0
1   1   1   0
1   1   100 1
1   1   10  1
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
10  10  10  10

$ cat zz | sort -n -k1,3 
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0
1   1   0   0
1   1   1   0
1   1   100 1
1   1   10  1
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
10  10  10  10
```

Desired output (with numeric sorting):

```
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0
1   1   0   0
1   1   1   0
1   1   1   1
1   1   10  1
1   1   100 1
2   2   2   2
10  10  10  10
```

What options should I use in sort to get my desired output i.e. sorted in numeric order

Comment: `sort -k1n -k3n`

Comment: @anubhava $ cat -A zz | sort -n -k1,3
$
0^I0^I0^I0$
0^I1^I0^I0$
1^I0^I0^I0$
1^I1^I0^I0$
1^I1^I100^I1$
1^I1^I10^I1$
1^I1^I1^I0$
1^I1^I1^I1$
2^I2^I2^I2$
10^I10^I10^I10$

Comment: @JamesBrown, yes it works. can you pls explain in ans portion for help of others too?

Comment: @anubhava sort -k1,3n zz-- does not work, but sort -k1n -k3n works, sort -k1n -k2n -k3n works

Comment: I am also testing it on ubuntu and it works for me

Comment: So, what is the best alternative to ensure same result (numeric sorting) everywhere?